# Working in aerospace/mechanical/IT industry with domestic violence background?

Tags: career-development, united-states

I'm in my mid 20s working on a graduate degree in Aerospace Engineering.

I have had a clean record until early this year, where I was charged with 3 misdemeanor crimes (harassment, false imprisonment, and telephone obstruction), which are domestic violence crimes because these were alleged to have occurred in a domestic relations situation. So now I have a domestic violence background. I don't currently have any convictions. My case is set for jury trial, and there is a potential that I would be convicted.

I am considering the worst case scenario, which would be me being convicted for all 3 DV crimes. Would this effectively make me unemployable in the aerospace industry with a DV conviction? What about in mechanical/IT industries? Does anyone know of anyone working in these industries with a domestic violence record? I'm sure there are people with criminal backgrounds working for these companies, but I feel DV is considered more severe and it has a very negative connotation.

Comment: Felony?  Any felony is going to nix some opportunities.  DV is probably better than a drug charge or theft but I am only speculating.

Comment: Gov. positions probably not likely which also cuts down on who will pay for aerospace work.  You can likely get a commercial job somewhere so long as you adhere to any reform rulings by the court, but it's going to be an upwards climb.

Comment: All I can say is good luck.  It doesn't matter what industry or the details of your alleged crime, employers will notice that big red flag.

Comment: Paparazzi: No, 3 misdemeanors. I was thinking DV would be worse than drug/theft crimes.

Comment: Usually, it's just felonies that block you.  See a lawyer to get those expunged though, and eliminate the problem entirely.

Comment: Any plea offers?  Do you have a good lawyer?  I was a (not very good evidently) witness for the prosecution in a case was punching his then GF in the head.  He was found not guilty.

Comment: Pete B. Yes, I was offered the most favorable plea offer (aside from a dismissal). The plea offer is that I plead guilty to telephone harassment (which is the lowest misdemeanor). Telephone harassment is defined as "Makes a telephone call or causes a telephone to ring repeatedly, whether or not a conversation ensues, with no purpose of legitimate conversation". I would be pleading guilty to this, and b/c it's a DV case, I would have to take a DV evaluation and take at least 36 weeks worth of DV classes.

Comment: Pete B. As a carry on. I decided to go to trial, but now I am second guessing myself. My lawyer says this is a winnable case, but also a losable case, depending on who the jury believes. This is also a he said, she said case, and these cases are going to be based on credibility. I have alleged that the alleged victim is lying and her motive for lying is because we share a infant child together, who I have primary custody of issued by the district court last year, which has made her extremely vindictive. I think I have one of the best lawyers in my state.

Comment: Richard U: In my state, expungement is not allowed on non-juvenile records. For adult records, we have something called a "seal." But I read that even if I seal my record, the FBI can still pick it up in a security clearance and I'd have to disclose it on the SF86.

Comment: DV may have a higher social stigma but employers are more about bottom line.

Comment: I have tagged this US, because of your wording. The answer seems to imply US as well. If that's wrong, please retag it with the correct country.

Comment: It almost certainly would cost you any job requiring a security clearance which is alot of jobs in that field.

Answer (score 4):

Would being convicted of domestic violence crimes make you unemployable in specific industries?

According to this web page, https://www.criminalwatchdog.com/faq/do-misdemeanors-show-on-background-checks, misdemeanors stay on your criminal record for life and they can show up when employers run background checks, depending on how thorough the background check is. The web page has additional information you might want to read.

The definition of domestic violence, according to http://ncadv.org/learn-more/what-is-domestic-violence, is the willful intimidation, physical assault, battery, sexual assault, and/or other abusive behavior as part of a systematic pattern of power and control perpetrated by one intimate partner against another.

In general an employer would avoid hiring someone who has been convicted of domestic violence crimes.  There are strong links between domestic violence and workplace violence, and so an employer would assume a lot of risk and potential liability hiring someone who has been convinced of domestic violence crimes. For more information:
-http://www.workplacesrespond.org/learn/the-facts/the-facts-on-the-workplace-and-domestic-violence
http://www.workplacesrespond.org/learn/the-facts/what-is-workplace-violence

Imagine if something happens at work and the victim discovers that the company knowingly put them at risk by hiring someone who had already been convicted of the same crime. This would likely qualify as corporate negligence.

The industries you specifically listed are all high profile, meaning that workplace violence related problems could potentially have a much bigger impact on the image or reputation of the business.  These industries are more lucrative, so the amount of money involved in a lawsuit could be much higher. These are professional industries where there is greater importance placed on interpersonal skills and the ability to work well with others. Finally, these are industries where you might end up working with information that is considered sensitive, confidential, proprietary, or even classified, which means that background checks are going to be much more thorough.

To give you an idea of the sensitivity, I work in a similar industry and failed a background check because I didn't realize my drivers license had expired. It caused a lot of problems and was super embarrassing, but luckily I was able to get it worked out and I passed when they ran the background check a second time.

I hope this helps...

Comment: If I seal my record, would they still be able to see the criminal background?

Comment: I don't believe you can seal your own records. Only a court may do this. Check your local laws pertaining to this.

Comment: Your not likely going to be able to seal a conviction the day after your found guilty (or you pled it out) otherwise every criminal would do that which would mean every criminal would have no criminal record

Comment: Ramhound: My state does not allow the seal of DV-related convictions. If you are convicted in trial court, it stays with you for life. No sealing. No expungement.

Answer (score 1):

This is locale and company specific, I've seen a convicted murderer become a Minister of Parliament.

These are not serious crimes, and if there is a demand for people with your skills and a shortage of candidates you should be ok. But all else being equal a clean record will get the job in front of you.

Drugs and stealing are the two major offenses that are automatic bars for many professions.

Comment: Not serious crimes?  Check out http://www.famfc.org/domestic-violence-awareness/after-effects-of-a-domestic-violence-conviction-1.  "statistics show there is about an 80% chance you will lose your job if convicted of domestic violence."

Comment: Jaw drops. Not serious crimes?  They sure as hell are serious crimes to any woman. I have had many friends hospitalized, threatened, stalked,  and some even had to change their names and move to another location. This is one of the worst crimes of all.

Comment: HLGEM: "To any woman?" What about "To any man?" Or is it just "To any woman?"